# Set collection color in outliner with Python

Tags: python, scripting, outliner

I have this script that creates the collection, but I have no clue where to add the color_tag to it that it works.
Thanks for the help.

This is the code or at least a piece:

```py
import bpy

collectionFound = False

for myCol in bpy.data.collections:
    print(myCol.name)
    if myCol.name == "PRODUCTION":
        collectionFound = True
        break
        
        
if collectionFound == False:
    production_collection_name = "PRODUCTION"
    production_collection = bpy.data.collections.new(production_collection_name)
    bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(production_collection)
```

Answer (score 7):

The color tag can be set through `collection.color_tag` if `collection` is an object of type `bpy.types.Collection`. The color is assigned through one of the possible enum values. The property `color_tag` is documented in [Blender's Python API docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Collection.html?highlight=color_tag#bpy.types.Collection.color_tag).

The modified example script looks for the first collection named "PRODUCTION" and gives it a red color. If no such collection can be found, it creates a new collection with that name and sets the color to orange.

Note: The displayed colors can be different depending on your theme settings in *Edit > Preferences > Themes > Collection Colors*.

```
import bpy

collection_name = "PRODUCTION"
collection_found = False

for collection in bpy.data.collections:
    if collection.name == collection_name:
        collection.color_tag = "COLOR_01"
        collection_found = True
        break

if not collection_found:
    collection = bpy.data.collections.new(collection_name)
    collection.color_tag = "COLOR_02"
    bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(collection)
```

Comment: I think you forgot to set `collection_found = True` unless I missed something ?

Comment: @Gorgious Ah yes, sorry about that. It's fixed now.

Comment: Hey Robert, thank you so much!! this works nicely!
I have a second question, what if you wanna have like a few Scene Collections and some subcollections? Would you declare all those names from the start?