How to assign a color to a collection upon creation?
Is there any way to assign a color to a collection at the time of creation instead of having to move to the outliner, right click, and select a color from the dropdown menu?

Not that I know. Where exactly would you like to click and select a color if not the Outliner? Or which other way of assigning would you prefer?

I would agree with Gordon, collection colors are tags. The official doc doesn't contain anything about a possible default color tag https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/collections/introduction.html#color-tagging.

Would the Python script in the answer to this question help?: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/262994/set-collection-color-in-outliner-with-python#262997 Here is the list of colors available: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy_types_enum_items/collection_color_items.html
